# sorting in react using a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have done this in React class components but I need to do this in react function component as I want to learn to convert class components to function components.

```
  onSortByPlatformAsc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = this.state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    this.setState({ listGames: sortByPlatform });
  };

  onSortByPlatformDesc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = this.state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    this.setState({ listGames: sortByPlatform.reverse() });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing so is nearly the same in functional components except for the part where you set the state.  You will have a state value and a function to set the state using the useState hook as shown below:

```
const [games, setGames] = useState({
 listGames:[]
})
```

Then all you need to do is call the setGames function with the values you want to set as below

```
    onSortByPlatformAsc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = this.state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    setGames({ listGames: sortByPlatform });
  };

  onSortByPlatformDesc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = this.state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    setGames({ listGames: sortByPlatform.reverse() });
  };
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: My useState is as follows  const [listGames, setListGames] = useState(JSONDATA) so i think setState will not work here

Answer (score 0):

Frankly it isn't that much different.
Differences in this case are mainly:

- `this` is no longer relevant.
- functions need to be declared like regular functions or consts, etc..
- `state` is no longer one object, though it can be if you want, but can also be seperate pieces of state, declared by the built-in `useState` hook.

The code you posted should look like this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [listGames, setListGames] = useState([]);

  const onSortByPlatformAsc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    setListGames(sortByPlatform);
  };

  const onSortByPlatformDesc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = state.listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );
    setListGames(sortByPlatform.reverse());
  };
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use state in functional component you should use `useState()` hook. In addition there is no `this` keyword in functional components.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
const [listGames, setListGames] = useState([])

onSortByPlatformAsc = () => {
    var sortByPlatform = listGames.sort((a, b) =>
      a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
    );

    setListGames(sortByPlatform);
};

onSortByPlatformDesc = () => {
  var sortByPlatform = listGames.sort((a, b) =>
    a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform)
  );

  setListGames(sortByPlatform.reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.sort` and `Array.prototype.reverse` both do in-place sorts and orderings. In other words, they mutate the array they operate over. If you are calling this on React state, it will mutate state, a major anti-pattern in React.

Assuming you've converted and stored the class-component `this.state.listGames` into a function component `listGames` `useState` React hook:

```
const [listGames, setListGames] = React.useState([]);
```

I suggest factoring the code a bit to create sorting and inverse sorting comparator functions:

```
const sortComparator = (a, b) => a.platform.localeCompare(b.platform);
const inverseSortComparator = (a, b) => sortComparator(b, a);
```

Use a functional state update to access the previous state, create a copy, then sort it using the comparator.

```
const onSortByPlatformAsc = () => {
  setListGames(listGames => listGames.slice().sort(sortComparator));
};
```

To do an inverted sort, again use a functional state update, create a copy, and then use an inverted sort comparator function to swap the sorting order.

```
const onSortByPlatformDesc = () => {
  setListGames(listGames => listGames.slice().sort(inverseSortComparator));
};
```